# Is a boolean interval of finite groups linearly primitive?

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, finite-groups, lattice-theory, computational-group-theory

Let $[H,G]$ be an interval of finite groups.

*Definition*: Let $W$ be a representation of $G$, and $X$ a subspace of $W$.
 Let the *fixed-point subspace* $W^{H}:=\{w \in W \ \vert \  kw=w \ , \forall h \in H  \}$.
Let the *pointwise stabilizer subgroup* $G_{(X)}:=\{ g \in G \  \vert \ gx=x \ , \forall x \in X \}$.

The interval $[H,G]$ is called *linearly primitive* if  $\exists V$ irred. complex repr. of $G$ with $G_{(V^H)} = H$.
*Remark*: We recover the usual definition of "linearly primitive" for groups by taking $H =\{ e \}$.

*Definition*: The subset lattice of $\{1, \dots , n \}$ is called the boolean lattice $B_n$ (see $B_3$ below).

[image]

**Question**: Is a boolean interval of finite groups linearly primitive?

Comment: Is perhaps this result of Tůma useful for answering this question? *Every algebraic lattice is isomorphic to an interval in the subgroup lattice of some group.*
See [DOI: 10.1016/0021-8693(89)90171-3](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0021-8693(89)90171-3),
[Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22every+algebraic+lattice%22+isomorphic+subgroup+interval),
[Google Books](https://www.google.com/books?q=%22every+algebraic+lattice%22+isomorphic+subgroup+interval),
[Google Scholar](https://www.google.com/scholar?q=%22every+algebraic+lattice%22+isomorphic+subgroup+interval).

Comment: Sorry, now I noticed that your question is about *finite* groups. But I will keep comment, just in case it is useful for other users reading this question.

Comment: Thanks. Anyway, the lattice $B_n$ is also realized by an inclusion of finte group (for example $G=\mathbb{Z}/p_1 \cdots p_n$ and $H=\{  e \}$). We can reformulate the question by: Can a $B_n$ lattice be realizable by a non linearly primitive inclusion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes**, it is the main result of the paper [arXiv:1708.02565v1](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1708.02565.pdf), Theorem 3.13.